# How to calculate score speed?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift3

I'm trying to calculate the speed at which a player accumulates score, so as to set different properties to the gameplay. I am however stuck on logic figuring out how to do it so it would constantly update, based on the current input.

So as to clean things up I created a blank Swift Xcode project with a button and two labels - one for Score, one for Speed (scoreSpeed).

The problem right now is that the displayed speed is 0, apparently because it fails to calculate the difference between the first score position (scorePos1) and the second one (scorePos2). I have a feeling it's to do with incorrect "getting" of the score value (or incorrect scorePos placing).

I am a beginner, so maybe there's a better way to do it.

Here's the code in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTimer()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    var score = Double()
    var scorePos1 = Double()
    var scorePos2 = Double()
    var scoreSpeed = Double()
    var timerInt: Double = 5.0

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
        score += 1.0
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        scorePos1 = score
    }

    var speedTimer = Timer()

    func startTimer(){
        //speedTimer.invalidate()
        speedTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timerInt, target: self, selector: #selector(calcSpeed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func calcSpeed(){
        scorePos2 = score
        scoreSpeed = (scorePos2 - scorePos1)/timerInt
        speedLabel.text = "Speed: \(scoreSpeed)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you call this method `startTimer()` in `viewDidLoad` as it will always return 0. Secondly you have assign `scorePos2` and `scorePos1` both to `score`. so there difference will always be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button press sets `scorePos1` to `score` and your `calcSpeed` function sets `scorePos2` to `score`, so they are both score.

Set `scorePos2` to score *after* you calculate the speed.

Also, would be

```
scorePos1 - scorePos2
```

if `scorePos2` is the historical account.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I defined another timer with a different interval that has a sole function for getting the historical variable and changed the calculation to `scorePos1 - scorePos2`.
Still I wonder if there's no other way to store variables in memory for short times.